# Different click event target in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

If press mouse button inside input element and drag out to the header before releasing in Chrome we will see header as click event target, but in Firefox we will see input field as event target. What the reason of  this differences in event handling and how to implement Firefox behaviour in Chrome.

Also safari in this case doesn't dispatch event.

Interesting thing. This 'incorrect' behaviour can be reproduced in Chrome only if you start click event on input field and drag out to header. If you start from header and finish it on input field you will see expected event target (header).

Tried to do something with poitner-events and eventListener options, but no results.

I've created [this simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/SemyenPukhov/48tqv0y7/) for checking this difference.

Here is example of layout where this case can be reproduced.

```
<div class="header" onclick="handleClick(event)">
  <input type="text" class="input" onclick="handleClick(event)">
</div>
```

Comment: you can't have a <p> inside another <p>

Comment: I actually found the same thing today. I was trying to debug a weird behaviour of https://material-ui.com/components/click-away-listener/. Note that Safari behaves like Firefox.